# GNU grub (Can't access Ubuntu or Windows)

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows-8, ubuntu-one, gnu

I have Windows 8.1 installed on the internal hard drive of my computer, and I had Ubuntu installed on an external hard drive. I just moved my computer and turned it off and unplugged everything and when I open it up, I get a screen that says:

```
GNU Grub version2.02~beta2~-9ubuntu1.3  Minimal BASH-like line editing is supported.
```

After that, it basically says TAB shows possible commands. If the commands differ between other Grub menus, I will type out all of the possible commands.

Usually when I start my computer, it goes through this purple screen where I can choose to start Windows normally, and so it starts normally, I choose Windows again in a menu and it boots. That is not the case here. I have to go through Ubuntu to get to Windows. I think it doesn't realize that it has access to its files on my external hard drive or something. In any case, I cannot access Windows, which I always use. When I type exit, it brings up a boot menu, the options of which are (no hyphen)

```
HDD/SSD - :TOSHIBA MQ01ABD100(S1)
ODD - :HL-DT-ST DVDRAM GU90N(PM)
LAN - :Realtek PXE
USB - :
<Enter Setup>
<HDD Recovery>
```

All of the selections bring me back to the GNU screen, except the HDD recovery option, however I'm not sure what exactly what that will do. I don't want my files to be deleted because there are important files I do not have copies of on my internal hard drive. The lack of anything in USB supports my idea that it may not realize it has access to the external hard drive where Ubuntu is installed.

Comment: did you reconnect the External drive? grubs configuration file (the menu) is stored in the ubuntu partition. Asuming this is an EFI system, the USB selection will be empty unless the is an EFI partition with a bootloader  on a USB drive.

Comment: Yes, I reconnected it, but it doesn't help it at all. I couldn't tell you of it is EFI or not. I have no idea.

Comment: The external hardrive is connected through a USB port, it's just a large 2 TB one.

Comment: does it use a USB 3 inteface? perhaps you connect to wrong port. also verify that USB boot is enabled in system settings.

Comment: I'm not sure whether is 3 or 2.

Comment: I didn't mean to send that one yet. I switched it to another USB port just to make sure (I have it connected to the same port it usually is, and I've never had problems with it before), and this time, everything went like normal. Purple screen, boot to Windows. I am very relieved to see that. Now I just want to uninstall Ubuntu so I don't have these types of problems anymore.

Comment: sounds like it had a bad connection. Sometimes this happens and is unrelated to ubuntu.

Comment: That might be the case. Regardless, thank you a lot :) I wouldn't have thought of that. Tonight it's too late for me to mess around with but tomorrow I'm gonna go ahead and try to look up ways to uninstall Ubuntu so I don't have problems like this again. This isn't the first time I've had difficulty getting to Windows.

Comment: The reason for this is because /EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi has been replaced with GRUBs. However what confuses me is why aren't given an option from within UEFI to boot Windows Boot manager.

Comment: Could you please run [Boot-Info](//help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info) and [edit] your question to include a link to its resulting info log? Thanks.